# How can I have a shared data storage amongst React hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have created a couple of hooks to manage lists. These are some of them:

- usePageSize
- usePageNumber
- useFiltering
- useSorting
- useApi

The problem is that they are a mesh. They need some common data.

For example, the `usePageNumber` needs to access the loaded data, and if there is no data it has to set the page number to 1. On ther other hand, `useApi` needs to know the current `pageNumber` to send it to the API and get the appropriate page data.

In components we have the `useContext` and `React.createContext`. They both work well to share data between components.

But now I want to be able to share data between hooks. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options:

- LocalStorage or SessionStorage stores the data in the browser.
- In vanilla React you can also `useContext` in hooks, for example

```
const usePageSize = () => {
  const contextValue = useContext(...)
}
```

- A lot of 3rd party libraries can accomplish a shared state, like `zustand`, `signals` etc

For the purposes you mentioned, context would make sense because it only persists data between page loads. SessionStorage could also work if you want data to persist between loads, but not between sessions.

Comment: Thank you. But that `useContext` won't work. It needs a component in which the `<ContextProvider>` is set at a higher level. I use my hooks before creating that context. In fact, these hooks create the common data for that `ListContext`.

Comment: Yeah, you need a context on a higher level. You could introduce another context one level up, so you have a shared context for these hooks and a derived context for inner components. Otherwise I suggest using one of the other options.